# Can't see the directory I created on Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I was following a tutorial and he created a directory called "Menu" so I did that I created it.

But it does not appear on android studio but on the file explorer it does

What can I do to fix this and make android studio show ne the directory because I can't access it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WKkZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D86zo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnmFk.png)

I uninstalled android studio and installed it again.

I clickd "Reload all from disk" and "Sync project with gradle files"

Comment: Size matters...

Comment: Did the tutorial author actually create the "Menu" folder in the res directory!? (that's where I see it in your explorer attachment) You'd probably see the directory if you changed your view from Android to Project. But the key here is that Menu is not a recognised type of resource

Answer (score 0):

Menu is a type of resource on Android.

The Android Developer website does mention XML menu resource and the location `/res/menu` under the [Define a menu in XML section](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/menus#xml).

In Android and Android Studio projects, the naming convention for resources directories is significant. It generally requires lowercase names.

I can repeat your issue. The problem was just caused by the capital letter "M".

Please check your screenshot. You will see you have named the directory `Menu` instead of `menu`. That is why Android Studio is not showing that directory under the tree.

If you try to name it `menu`, it will be able to show up properly, no matter if you have created that within or outside of Android Studio.

Alternatively, you can right-click on the `res` directory on Android Studio, choose **New** - **Android Resource File**, pick the resource type **menu**, and create the XML menu file you need using the UI. There you will see Android Studio prefills the directory name `menu` (in lowercase) automatically for you.

[image: Android Studio: Adding new menu resources through the UI dialog2]